# Adding result set to SSIS SQL task with Executable

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

How can an instance of ExecuteSQLTask (Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask) be added to a DtsEventHandler?

Building the ExecuteSQLTask is [straight forward](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Execute-SQL-Task-in-Code.aspx), but adding it to an event handler may require some kind of casting.

I prefer not creating it this way, because I cannot add parameter mapping to the result set this way. Unless there is a way to add parameters to the Executable below?

```
     DtsEventHandler ehOnError = (DtsEventHandler)package.EventHandlers.Add("OnError");

 Executable execOnError = ehOnError.Executables.Add("STOCK:SQLTask");
            TaskHost thOnError = (TaskHost)execOnError;
            thOnError.Name = "sql_Exec_LogMessage_Error";
            thOnError.SetExpression("SqlStatementSource", "@[User::sql_LogMessageError]");
            thOnError.Properties["Connection"].SetValue(thOnError, cmag.ID);
// Parameter mapping?
```

Comment: I'm not following you. Or rather, I see what they're doing on the referenced article but not following what you are attempting to do that the referenced article does not. Could you edit it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need the ExecuteSQLTask now, and then follow their Parameter Binding example?

```
Executable execOnError = ehOnError.Executables.Add("STOCK:SQLTask");
TaskHost thOnError = (TaskHost)execOnError;
thOnError.Name = "sql_Exec_LogMessage_Error";
thOnError.SetExpression("SqlStatementSource", "@[User::sql_LogMessageError]");
thOnError.Properties["Connection"].SetValue(thOnError, cmag.ID);

ExecuteSQLTask task = thOnError.InnerObject as ExecuteSQLTask;
...
task.ParameterBindings.Add();
IDTSParameterBinding parameterBinding = task.ParameterBindings.GetBinding(0);
parameterBinding.DtsVariableName = "User::Variable";
parameterBinding.ParameterDirection = ParameterDirections.Input;
...
```